# How to display text when a glyphicon is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a "right glyph arrow" and a Heading to appear on the screen and upon clicking, it should turn into "down glyph arrow" and display some text. Again, when the down arrow is clicked the text should disappear and the arrow should change to right icon.

Please check the screenshot to help you understand better.

[image]

[image]

The following is my code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-right').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-down');
    $("div").animate({
      height: 'toggle'

    });
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i> </a>

<div>This text appears once the right glyph arrow is clicked.</div>
```

The problem with my code is, it displays the right glyph as well as the text once the page loads. I just want the right icon to be displayed first and once it's clicked the text should appear.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @HarshSanghani: Or better yet, a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button) right here on site.

Comment: Side note: You can toggle multiple classes at the same time: `.toggleClass("glyphicon-arrow-right glyphicon-arrow-down")`

Comment: Just replace your div markup by '<div style="display:none;">This text appears once the right glyph arrow is clicked.</div>'

Comment: you can also use Jquery UI according for this functionality. Reference link https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this**

**CSS:**

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hidden">This text appears once the right glyph arrow is clicked.</div>
```

First it should be hidden, so add the class "hidden" to apply the style.

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/4qwzpx52/1/)

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy! It works now. I'm amazed to know how to get this thing work, in more than one way (after looking at other comments). Thank once again, good day! (:

Answer (score 1):

`toggleClass` can accept more than one class and it would be easier to use `slideToggle` than `animate`:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-right, glyphicon-arrow-down');
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

**css**

```
div {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided your CSS, which makes it hard to diagnose the problem.

However, something like this should do what you need;

```
#menu-toggle + div{
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Although I would recommend you simply start the div off with

```
#menu-toggle + div{
    display:none;
}
```

and use the JQuery animation of fadeIn() or slideDown() on the div.

If there will be loits of these drop-downs, you should of course select by class and not by ID.

Comment: My bad that I didn't add any CSS. Thank you for the response btw. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbKzvr)**

add class for div as name `showtext`

```
$('.showtext').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for responding with a Demo. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your div markup by below:

```
<div>This text appears once the right glyph arrow is clicked.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain the same behaviour **without** `jQuery`, just using `css`.
Using an `input[type=checkbox]`, a `label`. It is more flexible since you could also use `transitions` and don't imply a dependency (like `jQuery`).

[Here is de demo](http://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/5394a63221097a1d411541e48ebe7ff8?editors=1100) only using `css`.

Comment: Awesome man! Never struck my mind I could just use CSS to get this done. Thank you!

Comment: np, `CSS` is awesome and there are lot of things you can do without `js`.